Snail matrix in Java - version III (generalizing)
Once again, in the previous version, 
Alexander Ivanchenko helped me with his awesome answer.
Now, I have improved the toString() and, also, generalized the class to handle matrices of any dimensions, not only square matrices. Given an \$m \times n\$-matrix, we start setting its elements \$1, 2, \ldots mn\$ from the top left location clockwise at the outermost feasible non-occupied cycle.
Code
package com.github.coderodde.fun.snailmatrix;

import java.util.Arrays;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.joining;

public class SnailMatrix {
    
    private static final String BASE_FORMAT = "%%%dd";
    
    /**
     * The actual matrix data.
     */
    private final int[][] data;
    
    /**
     * Constructs this snail matrix.
     * 
     * @param n the width and height of this matrix. 
     */
    private SnailMatrix(final int width, final int height) {
        this.data = new int[height][width];
    }
    
    /**
     * Creates a snail matrix of dimensions {@code n x n}.
     * 
     * @param width the width of the matrix.
     * @param height the height of the matrix.
     * 
     * @return the snail matrix.
     */
    public static SnailMatrix ofSize(final int width, final int height) {
        checkDimensions(width, height);
        
        var matrix = new SnailMatrix(width, height);
        var initializer = new MatrixInitializer(matrix);
        
        initialize(initializer);
        
        return matrix;
    }
    
    /**
     * Initializes the matrix.
     * 
     * @param initializer the intializer object.
     */
    private static void initialize(final MatrixInitializer initializer) {
        int value = 1;
        
        while (initializer.hasNext()) {
            initializer.set(value++);
            initializer.next();
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Returns the value from column {@code x} and row {@code y}.
     * 
     * @param x the {@code x}-coordinate of the target cell.
     * @param y the {@code y}-coordinate of the target cell.
     * 
     * @return the value of the target cell.
     */
    public int get(final int x, final int y) {
        return data[y][x];
    }
    
    public int getWidth() {
        return data[0].length;
    }
    
    public int getHeight() {
        return data.length;
    }
    
    public int getCapacity() {
        return getWidth() * getHeight();
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Arrays.stream(data)
                     .map(this::rowToString)
                     .collect(joining(System.lineSeparator()));
    }
    
    private String rowToString(final int[] row) {
        final var cellFormat = getCellFormat();
        
        return Arrays.stream(row)
                     .mapToObj(cellFormat::formatted)
                     .collect(joining(" "));
    }
    
    private String getCellFormat() {
        return BASE_FORMAT.formatted(String.valueOf(getCapacity())
                          .length());
    }
    
    private void set(final int x, final int y, final int value) {
        data[y][x] = value;
    }
    
    private static void checkDimensions(final int width, final int height) {
        if (width < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    String.format(
                            "Width too small: %d. Must be at least 1.", 
                            width));
        }
        
        if (height < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    String.format(
                            "Height too small: %d. Must be at least 1.", 
                            height));
        }   
    }
    
    /**
     * This class implements the snail matrix initializer.
     */
    private static final class MatrixInitializer {
        private static final int[][] DIRECTIONS = 
                new int[][] {
                    {1, 0},
                    {0, 1},
                    {-1, 0},
                    {0, -1},
                };
        
        private final SnailMatrix matrix;
        private int direction = 0;
        private int x; 
        private int y;
        
        private MatrixInitializer(final SnailMatrix matrix) {
            this.matrix = matrix;
        }
        
        private void set(int value) {
            matrix.set(x, y, value);
        }
        
        private boolean hasNext() {
            return isValid(x, y) && !isInitialized(x, y);
        }
        
        private boolean isValid(final int x, final int y) {
            return 0 <= x && x < matrix.getWidth()
                && 0 <= y && y < matrix.getHeight();
        }
        
        private boolean isInitialized(final int x, final int y) {
            return matrix.get(x, y) != 0;
        }
        
        private void next() {
            checkDirection();
            x += xDelta();
            y += yDelta();
        }
        
        private void checkDirection() {
            final int nextX = x + xDelta();
            final int nextY = y + yDelta();
            
            if (!isValid(nextX, nextY) || isInitialized(nextX, nextY)) {
                changeDirection();
            }
        }
        
        private int xDelta() {
            return DIRECTIONS[direction][0];
        }
        
        private int yDelta() {
            return DIRECTIONS[direction][1];
        }
        
        private void changeDirection() {
            direction = (direction + 1) % DIRECTIONS.length;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int width = 5;
        final int height = 3;
        
        System.out.println(SnailMatrix.ofSize(width, height));
    }
}

Program output
 1  2  3  4  5
12 13 14 15  6
11 10  9  8  7

Critique request
As always, is there anything to improve?

Indentation is confusing here:
    private String getCellFormat() {
        return BASE_FORMAT.formatted(String.valueOf(getCapacity())
                          .length());
    }

should be:
    private String getCellFormat() {
        return BASE_FORMAT.formatted(String.valueOf(getCapacity())
                                     .length());
    }


While you now have a generalized SnailMatrix, it does not implement any general Matrix functionality (addition, multiplication, transpose, ...) other than printing.  The snail-pattern is just one of possibly many matrix initializations.  You really should have a separate Matrix class (where operations can be defined), and then ...
class SnailMatrix {
    public void static fill(Matrix &m) { ...}
}

... which stores the snail pattern into an existing matrix.  Now you can't rely on the Matrix initially being entirely zero; you'll have to zero-fill it yourself, or determine another way of determining which elements have not yet been filled in.
Of course, this opens yet another can of worms: what kind of Matrix?  As you'd want this to work with Matrix<int>, the ideal will have to wait for Valhalla...
